# transform input field in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. Within this form, I have an `input` field. I want to change some `input` field in the text area. I receive this form from an external source, so I can't change the html. How make this in js/jquery?

This is an example:

```
<label for="MMERGE12" class="MMERGE12-label"><span class="MMERGE12-label">categorie trattate</span>
                                                                        <input id="yikes-easy-mc-form-1-MMERGE12" name="MMERGE12" placeholder="" class="yikes-easy-mc-text" type="text" value="">

                                    <!-- description -->
                                    <p class="form-field-description"><small></small></p>                                   
                                                                        </label>
```

**SOLVED WITH THIS CODE :**

```
var input    = document.getElementById('yikes-easy-mc-form-1-MMERGE12'),
    textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.id    = input.id;
textarea.cols  = 40;
textarea.rows  = 5;
textarea.value = input.value;
textarea.name = input.name;
input.parentNode.replaceChild(textarea, input);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Explain it better if you want us to help you. What data do you recieve. You only want to set value to textbox input? If so, just go $("#yikes-easy-mc-form-1-MMERGE12").val("value you want to insert");

Comment: a js script generate this form from external resource(external domain) , now every field is imput type , i want 1 imput field became a textarea, but i don't have possibility to change a html code

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Create a new textarea
    var textarea = jQuery("<textarea></textarea>");

    //Select the input 
    var input = jQuery("#yikes-easy-mc-form-1-MMERGE12");

    //Asign the value, id, name from the input to the textarea
    textarea.val(input.val());
    textarea.attr('id', input.attr('id'));
    textarea.attr('name', input.attr('name'));
    //You can copy any other attribute you like here

    //Finally do the replacement
    input.reaplceWith(textarea);
```

you will probably need to wrap this in ready wrapper `jQuery(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ })` if you do it on load or if you load it with ajax just execute this code after the data has been attached to the DOM

Comment: i tried this code , but never change , and in console never error.                          jQuery(document).ready(function() {//Create a new textarea
    var textarea = jQuery("<textarea></textarea>");

    //Select the input 
    var input = jQuery("#yikes-easy-mc-form-1-MMERGE12");

    //Asign the value, id, name from the input to the textarea
    textarea.val(input.val());
    textarea.attr('id', input.attr('id'));
    textarea.attr('name', input.attr('name'));
    //You can copy any other attribute you like here

    //Finally do the replacement
    input.reaplceWith(textarea);})

Comment: well then either wrap it in the document ready event or put it and the end of the HTML just before the </body>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var input = $("#yikes-easy-mc-form-1-MMERGE12");
        var textArea = $("<textarea></textarea>").attr({
            id: input.attr("id"),
            name: input.attr("name"),                    
            value: input.val()
        });
        // class is set separately because "class" is a reserved word ...
        textArea.attr("class", input.attr("class"));
        //insert textarea right after original input, and remove input
        input.after(textArea).remove();
});
```